# Trying to remotely compile, using the command line, a Java program with multiple dependencies that I can currently only compile locally in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation, executable-jar

Some weeks ago at work I took over a Java-based back-end web application written using Eclipse. The nature of the application is that it cannot be adequately tested locally, and instead changes need to be tested on our testing network (which involves pushing the changes to an AWS Micro server that we connect to via SSH).

Until now, I pushed changes in the same way as my predecessor: compile the program using Eclipse's Export to Runnable JAR File option, then scp the jar to the remote server and run it. However, this process has a huge problem. While compilation takes only seconds, the jar is well over 30MB, and pushing the entire thing from the office to the remote server over our fairly ordinary internet connection takes well over 10 minutes. If I'm having a particularly bad day and, say, introduce several minor bugs to the code and then discover them one by one, I can easily end up losing an hour or more in total twiddling my thumbs while pushing the whole jar over and over for a series of one-line changes.

Clearly, a saner solution than scping the entire jar for every change would be to simply remotely pull only the changed .java files from source control, and then compile the new version entirely remotely. However, I'm quite new to Java (and indeed programming generally) and all my Java work has been on existing Eclipse projects that I've taken over partway through development. As such, I know very little about compiling Java, and I have found the tutorials about this online are mostly either opaque or completely fail to address the question of how to compile code that uses external libraries.

I will relate here what information about the project's dependencies I can find from Eclipse, and my questions are these: what do I need to copy to the remote server, and where do I need to put it, to be able to compile remotely? What tools, if any, do I need to install on the remote server to be able to compile there? And once I've got everything set up, what do I actually type at the command line to get it to compile?

Anyway, here's what I know about the dependencies and directory structure (I've anonymised our application name by calling it “bunnies”):

- The application source code is located in bunnies/src
- We compile to bunnies/bin/main.jar
- bunnies/dependencies contains three jars of external libraries that we use.
- Right-clicking on the project in Eclipse, going to the Java Build Path section, and selecting the Libraries tab, I see

  - the three libraries above 
    (appearing in the form, e.g. “json-simple-1.1.1.jar - /home/mark/workspace/bunnies/dependencies”)
  - a fourth jar file in another location 
    (“M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/r09/guava-r09.jar - /home/mark/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/r09/guava-r09.jar”)
  - JRE System Library [java-6-openjdk-i386]
- But there's more! We also use two libraries, mahout-core and mahout-integration, that are included as separate projects in the same workspace rather than as jar files in the dependencies folder. They appear by name on the Projects tab of the Java Build Path section of the bunnies project, and are located at /home/mark/workspace/mahout-core and /home/mark/workspace/mahout-integration respectively.
- Since I am not a Java whiz, perhaps there are also some other hidden dependencies I'm missing, that don't appear in any of the places I've looked so far?

If anyone can walk me through the steps of compiling this huge mess from the command line, without needing to use the Export option in Eclipse, so that I can ultimately compile it all remotely, I would be highly appreciative.

Comment: Maybe you can run your web app to allow remote debugging. And then you attach from your local machine to the remote JVM. This may allow you to hot-deploy the JVM with compiled classes during your tests.

Comment: Here is an example: [Configuring Jetty, Maven, and Eclipse together with Hot Swap](http://www.clickonchris.com/2010/05/configuring-jetty-maven-and-eclipse-together-with-hot-deploy/). Not saying it works with your configuration but it might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). It's a build-suite for Java, sort of like an XML based Makefile system.

I have a Java system running on a remote server. I have a directory structure separated into /src and /build. I then just scp the .java files from my local machine to the /src folder and build using ant.

Comment: A further pointer for anyone else trying to solve the same problem in future: you can give yourself a headstart by selecting the option from within the 'Export' wizard in Eclipse that makes it save to disk the ant script it uses for jarring stuff. Ultimately there doesn't seem to be any substitute for writing a big ugly ant script mostly by hand, though.